# Simple Ruby Input Scraper

Tags: ruby, hash, char

I'm completely new to ruby and wanted to ask for some help with this ruby script.

it's supposed to take in a string and find out which character occurs the most frequently. It does this using a hash, it stores all the characters in a hash and then iterates through it to find the one with greatest value. As of right now it doesn't seem to be working properly and i'm not sure why. It reads the characters in properly as far as i can tell with print statements. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

```
puts "Enter the string you want to search "
input = gets.chomp

charHash = Hash.new

input.split("").each do |i| 
    if charHash.has_key?(i)
        puts "incrementing"
        charHash[i]+=1
    else
        puts"storing"
        charHash.store(i, 1)
    end
end

goc = "" 
max = 0 
charHash.each { |key,value| goc = key  if value > max  }


puts "The character #{goc} occurs the most frequently"
```

Comment: Ruby has no `++` operator. use `charHash[i] += 1`. Also, next time, please google your error message first.

Comment: FACEPALM. I GOOGLE SEARCHED IT TOO. gah. Thanks. edited.

Comment: This sounds like a ubiquitous homework assignment.

Comment: We use snake_case for variables and methods in Ruby. CamelCase is used for classes and Modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major issues with you code:

1. As commented by Holger Just, you have to use `+= 1` instead of `++`
2. `charHash.store(:i, 1)` stores the symbol `:i`, you want to store `i`

Fixing these results in a working code (I'm using snake_case here):

```
char_hash = Hash.new

input.split("").each do |i|
  if char_hash.has_key?(i)
    char_hash[i] += 1
  else
    char_hash.store(i, 1)
  end
end
```

You can omit the condition by using `0` as your default hash value and you can replace `split("").each` with [`each_char`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-each_char):

```
char_hash = Hash.new(0)

input.each_char do |i|
  char_hash[i] += 1
end
```

Finally, you can pass the hash into the loop using [`Enumerator#with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object):

```
char_hash = input.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |i, h| h[i] += 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something but it seems that instead of

```
charHash.each { |key,value| goc = key  if value > max  }
```

you need something like

```
charHash.each do |key,value| 
  if value > max then
    max = value
    goc = key
  end
end
```

Notice the `max = value` statement. In your current implementation (i.e. without updating the max variable), every character that appears in the text at least once satisfies the condition and you end up getting the last one.